# Change default extensions location for remote development in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a visual studio code installed in a desktop. As I don't have any runtime environments installed in it, the source code repository is kept in the remote server where the runtime and other dependencies are available, so SSH connection is established from the VS code to update the source code.

I'm installing few extensions using VS code in the remote server where the source code and runtime are available. It gets installed in my home directory(/home/myname/.vscode-server)by default on the remote server.

As I have very limited disk space in my home directory, I want to change the extension location of vs code. Can you guide me here?. Your insights will be helpful. Thank you !!!

PS: Can't install VS code in the remote server due to limited access rights.

Answer (score 0):

It has been well discussed on GitHub under https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/472 and `remote.SSH.serverInstallPath` is the current solution.